# Pandas count occurrence within column on condition being satisfied

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, group-by, size

I am trying to do count by grouping. see below input and output.

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['col1'] = ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b']
df['col2'] = [4,4,5,5,6,7,8]
df['col3'] = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

output:

```
   col4
0     2
1     2
2     2
3     2
4     1
5     1
6     1
```

Tried playing around with groupby and count, by doing:

```
s = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].sum()
```

and the output I got was

```
a     4       2
      5       2
b     6       1
      7       1
      8       1
```

how do I add it just as a column on the main df.

Thanks vm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) `len` or [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].transform(len)
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3  count
0    a     4     1      2
1    a     4     1      2
2    a     5     1      2
3    a     5     1      2
4    b     6     1      1
5    b     7     1      1
6    b     8     1      1
```

---

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].transform('size')
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3  count
0    a     4     1      2
1    a     4     1      2
2    a     5     1      2
3    a     5     1      2
4    b     6     1      1
5    b     7     1      1
6    b     8     1      1
```

But column `col3` is not necessary, you can use `col1` or `col2`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['col1'] = ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b']
df['col2'] = [4,4,5,5,6,7,8]

df['count'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col1'].transform(len)
df['count1'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col2'].transform(len)
print (df)
  col1  col2 count  count1
0    a     4     2       2
1    a     4     2       2
2    a     5     2       2
3    a     5     2       2
4    b     6     1       1
5    b     7     1       1
6    b     8     1       1
```

Comment: boom! thats what I wanted to not have col3 and was using it only to use 'sum' thanks vm!

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].transform(sum)
print (df)
  col1  col2  col3  count
0    a     4     1    2
1    a     4     1    2
2    a     5     1    2
3    a     5     1    2
4    b     6     1    1
5    b     7     1    1
6    b     8     1    1
```